dotnet gRPC Error: The request stream was aborted
I am busy converting WCF service to gRPC. One of the methods is to upload large file(s) via streaming. I am currenlty using .NET 6.0 for Server & Client
I followed the example that is provided from here
I keep on getting the following error,
System.IO.IOException: The request stream was aborted.  ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionAbortedException: The HTTP/2 connection faulted.
When I run the server (docker container) and client (WPF) locally, ie my PC, it works. But when I move the server to my test kubernetes cluster on a pod, I get the error as descibered above with a stacktrace.
System.IO.IOException: The request stream was aborted.  ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionAbortedException: The HTTP/2 connection faulted.    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)    at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()    at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2MessageBody.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder1.StateMachineBox1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)    at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.PipeExtensions.ReadStreamMessageAsync[T](PipeReader input, HttpContextServerCallContext serverCallContext, Func2 deserializer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder1.StateMachineBox1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.HttpContextStreamReader1.<MoveNext>g__MoveNextAsync|13_0(ValueTask1 readStreamTask)
at Grpc.Core.AsyncStreamReaderExtensions.ReadAllAsyncCore[T](IAsyncStreamReader1 streamReader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()    at Grpc.Core.AsyncStreamReaderExtensions.ReadAllAsyncCore[T](IAsyncStreamReader1 streamReader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
at KEY360.FacadeCore.Services.Key360Stream.UploadFile(IAsyncStreamReader1 requestStream, ServerCallContext context) in KeyStream.cs:line 339    at KEY360.FacadeCore.Services.Key360Stream.UploadFile(IAsyncStreamReader1 requestStream, ServerCallContext context) in KeyStream.cs:line 339
at KEY360.FacadeCore.Services.Key360Stream.UploadFile(IAsyncStreamReader1 requestStream, ServerCallContext context) in KeyStream.cs:line 404    at Grpc.Shared.Server.ClientStreamingServerMethodInvoker3.ResolvedInterceptorInvoker(IAsyncStreamReader1 requestStream, ServerCallContext resolvedContext)    at Grpc.Shared.Server.ClientStreamingServerMethodInvoker3.ResolvedInterceptorInvoker(IAsyncStreamReader1 requestStream, ServerCallContext resolvedContext)
Here is my client code & server code.
Client

// some other code here, but it just get the client and opens the file into a filestream
// and then calls the client UploadFileAsync
try
{
    // Ensure the stream is positioned at the beginning
    //
    if (stream.CanSeek)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }

    var streamInfo = new StreamInfo
    {
        AllowClientCaching = false,
        Exception = null,
        Length = stream.Length,
        Message = GetRequestStringJSon(transaction),
        NewDocumentID = newDocumentId,
        FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileForUpload),
        Success = true,
        ServerCachingGUID = Guid.Empty.ToString(),
    };

    response = await service.UploadFileAsync(stream, streamInfo, JsonMetaData, ct);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    // Handle cancellation
    Console.WriteLine("Upload canceled.");
}
catch (IOException ioEx)
{
    // Handle I/O exceptions specifically
    Console.WriteLine($"I/O Exception: {ioEx.Message}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle all other exceptions
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
}

When UploadFileAsync it called, the catch is triggered, on the (Exception ex) catch line.
public async Task<UploadResponse> UploadFileAsync(Stream data, StreamInfo info , Metadata metadata, CancellationToken? ct = null)
        {
            using (var call = _client.UploadFile(metadata))
            {
                int bufferSize = 1024 * 32; //32kb
                var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int size = 0;
                int total;
                bool fileRead = false;
                var chk = 1;
                int chunkTotal = int.Parse((data.Length / bufferSize).ToString());
                if (data.Length % bufferSize > 0)
                    chunkTotal++;
                while (true)
                {
                    total = await data.ReadAsync(buffer);
                    if (total == 0) break;
                    fileRead = true;

                    await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new PutRequest
                    {
                        Data = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(buffer[0..total]),
                        Offset = size,
                        Info = new Protos.StreamInfo
                        {
                            AllowClientCaching = info.AllowClientCaching,
                            Exception = null,
                            FileName = info.FileName,
                            Length = info.Length,
                            Message = info.Message,
                            NewDocumentID = info.NewDocumentID,
                            ServerCachingGUID = info.ServerCachingGUID,
                            Success = info.Success
                        }
                    }, ct.GetValueOrDefault());
                    if (ct != null && ct.Value.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        break;
                        ct.Value.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    }

                   
                    size += total;
                    chk++;
                }
                if (!fileRead)
                {
                    await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new PutRequest
                    {
                        Offset = 0,
                        Info = new Protos.StreamInfo
                        {
                            AllowClientCaching = info.AllowClientCaching,
                            Exception = null,
                            FileName = info.FileName,
                            Length = info.Length,
                            Message = info.Message,
                            NewDocumentID = info.NewDocumentID,
                            ServerCachingGUID = info.ServerCachingGUID,
                            Success = info.Success
                        }
                    });
                }
                await call.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
                var done = await call.ResponseAsync;
                if (done.Success) // completed
                {
                    return new UploadResponse { Success = true, DocumentID = done.DocumentID, Exception = null };
                }
                else
                    return new UploadResponse { Success = false, DocumentID = done.DocumentID, Exception = done.Exception };
            }
        }

The server code looks like this:
public override async Task<UploadResponse> UploadFile(IAsyncStreamReader<PutRequest> requestStream, ServerCallContext context)
{
    _serviceContract.Context = context;
    try
    {
        var cts =  new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
        var token = cts.Token;
        if (context?.CancellationToken != null)
            token = _serviceContract.Context.CancellationToken;

        Facade.UploadStreamInfo uploadStream = null;

        var fileName = Path.GetTempFileName()   + ".upload";
        await using var file = File.Create(fileName);//, FileMode.Create);
        // THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE, ReadAllAsync, according to the stacktrace.
        await foreach(var data in requestStream.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken:token))
        {                                       
            try
            {                        
                if (data.Data.Length > 0)
                {
                    //file.Position = file.Length;
                    await file.WriteAsync(data.Data.ToByteArray());//, 0, bufferSize);
                }

            } catch (System.Exception ex) // this is not triggered, just some debug code.
            {
                await file.FlushAsync(token);
                file.Close();
                File.Delete(fileName);
                throw new RpcException(Status.DefaultCancelled, $"WriteError on Server with error. {ex.Message}");
                
            }
            if (uploadStream == null && requestStream.Current != null)
            {
                uploadStream = new Facade.UploadStreamInfo
                {
                    AllowClientCaching = requestStream.Current.Info.AllowClientCaching,
                    ByteStream = null,
                    FileName = requestStream.Current.Info.FileName,
                    NewDocumentID = requestStream.Current.Info.NewDocumentID,
                    Message = requestStream.Current.Info.Message,
                    Length = requestStream.Current.Info.Length,
                    ServerCachingGUID = requestStream.Current.Info.ServerCachingGUID,
                    Success = requestStream.Current.Info.Success
                };
            
            }
        }                

        await file.FlushAsync(token);
        file.Close();
        // some code removed here....
        // this code just move the uploaded file to the correct location, but it never gets here.
    } catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        //throw;
        return new UploadResponse { DocumentID = -1, Success = false, Exception = new Protos.Exception { Exceptiontree = ex.InnerException?.Message, Message = ex.Message, Type = ExceptionType.Error, Stacktrace = ex.StackTrace }  };
    }
    return new UploadResponse { DocumentID = -1, Success = false, Exception = new Protos.Exception { Message = "UploadFile failed due to unknown reason?", Type = ExceptionType.Validation } };
}

